# How to zoom this picture on scroller on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, zooming

Here below code:
Some people tell me use toolkit:gesture listener but it's not working on windows phone 8.1

```
<ListView Name="lst_img">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Name="img_intro" Source="{Binding link}" DoubleTapped="Image_DoubleTapped">

                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Image control inside of ScrollViewer:

```
<ListView Name="lst_img">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled">
                <Image Name="img_intro" Source="{Binding link}" DoubleTapped="Image_DoubleTapped">

                </Image>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```